# My app has just started getting rejected on Google Play due to App Actions

Tags: android, app-actions

So I have used App Actions in my app for a couple of years, last week I pushed a maintenence update that has been rejected by Google.  After some to and fro with Google Play support, the best I have managed to get out of them for the reason is "App Actions", and I should read the program requirements (the link they sent me has no program requirements section).

It's odd, as I have changed nothing in my app-actions area of code for a very long time, so I can only assume Google have quietly tightened some rules, and my app is no longer complaint.   Unfortunately, my crystal ball is currently away for cleaning, so unable to use it, I'm hoping someone else might have some real-world specific examples of how an app may not be compliant in the area of app-actions.

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, our crystal ball is also a bit cloudy. Can you update your question with the exact text they replied to you with? (Sometimes what they say does have meaning, even if it isn't clear.) It may also help if you clarified what BIIs you have and possibly show your `actions.xml` or `shortcuts.xml` file along with anything else that may illustrate how you are using App Actions. In short - the more you can provide, the better our chances are of being able to help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: After the review, we noticed that your app, XX (xx.yy.zz) was rejected during the App Actions program review.

Please carefully review the rejection notification sent to the email associated with your account for the remediation(s) and follow these steps:

Read through the App Actions program requirements for more details and make the necessary changes to your app.
Sign in to Play Console and submit the update to your app.
If you’ve reviewed the policy and feel our decision may have been in error, please contact the App Actions policy support team via this appeal form.

Comment: It's clearly a copy and paste response from Google, as there is no "program requirements" for App Actions on the link they provided.   They also don't send the remediation email that they claim.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are no straightforward rules specified by Google, so you have to go with some trial and error here to see what red flag(s) is your app raising. You can check [this article](https://developers.cafebazaar.ir/en/app-publish-guidelines/academy/blocked-play-protect) to see all the potential reasons on why Google may reject your app.